# When shortening the title of a book, should it be prefaced by a definite article?

Tags: definite-articles, latin, titles

I am writing a research paper which is concerned with Euler's book 'Introductio in analysin infinitorum'. May I refer to it as "the 'Introductio'"? And would it be wrong to simply refer to it as "Introductio"? Somehow the latter sounds wrong to me. Maybe it is because there are lots of "introductios" and therefore I feel the need to disambiguate using a definite article.

Also, to further generalise the question, is it the same if the title is given in English e.g. 'Introduction to the analysis of the infinite'? And can the same rules be generalised to similar book titles e.g. 'Foundations of Differential Calculus', 'Principia Mathematica'?

Comment: "Euler's _Introductio_" sounds better.

Comment: @Cascabel I agree and I have used that myself. TBH I am not just asking for myself but also for a student who has used the above-mentioned versions. So I would like to know their correctness.

Comment: The addition a superfluous English definite article to the title of a work used to be quite common for the Greek tragedies and Platonic dialogues, but I think the discipline of Classics has rather got away from the practice.

Comment: I agree with Cascabel - *"Euler's Introductio" sounds better.*: I would not use **the** Introductio as there are many such titles, e,g, Introductio Ad Prudentiam; Introductio Ad Latinam Blasoniam; Waltoni introductio ad lectionem linguarum orientalium; Introductio in libros Novi Testament;.Introductio ad Sapientiam; Introductio in Artem Diplomaticam; Introductio grammatico-critica in linguam Græcam, etc.

Comment: @Graybeard Yes but doesn't one say 'the tree' to refer to the tree which is most obviously meant in the context? Just because there are millions of trees does not stop us usually. Of course the full title must be introduced initially.